# Eclipse Code Assist inside method or type name

Tags: eclipse, visual-studio, adt

I'm used to Visual Studio, where when you start typing `System.Context` list will appear and you will be able to choose not only from type names that start with Context, but also from names like `ActivationContext`.

This gives me the ability to quickly find a method just by guessing it's name. Especially important when I'm beginning to learn to program for Android. For example, I was sure that `ListView` must have a method for setting `ListAdapter`, but I was dumb enough not to figure it will be just `setAdapter`. In VS I would just type `adapter` and `setAdapter` would have appeared.

Is there something similar in Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you can use the keyboard shortcut `Ctrl + Space` and it will try and suggest items for you.  You can do this after you have already started typing in a piece of the "suggestion".  It is a little more strict:

Example:  On a String object, you try and find, `equalsIgnoreCase()` (your string is called `test`).  Typing `test.e` then `CTRL + SPACE` gives three options (`endsWith`, `equals`, `equalsIgnoreCase`).  If you type `test.ignore` then `CTRL + SPACE` you get no results.  For filtering help, you can just use `test.` and then `CTRL + SPACE` and it will show all results so you can hunt that way.

Comment: Hmm... I wasn't clear. I've used Eclipse in the past for Java, but it was 3 years ago and I just can't remember if that feature (typing `test.ignore` and having a suggestion of `equalsIgnoreCase`) is available in Eclipse or if it has been added since then.

Comment: I hunted around and fooled around with the settings, and I couldn't get it to work where `test.ignore` would suggest `equalsIgnoreCase`.  The closest thing I found to getting it to preform "similar" in functionality to VS is setting it to instantly start suggesting on any character. 

`Window > Preferences:  Java > Editor > Content Assist` in there, add the string `abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ` to the "Auto Activation Triggers for Java".  It then completes after ANY letter, might help a bit :)